# How does Zend Registry work

Tags: zend-framework

I am wondering if Zend_Registry uses phpMemory, sessions or another method.

This question is more my curiousity.

```
Zend_Registry::set('test', array());
```

Comment: You could read the [code](http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/library/Zend/Registry.php) and work it out for yourself :)

Comment: Or you can also [read the manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.registry.html) :)

Comment: This is a valid and non-trivial question particularly if one just getting started with Zend. It is not immediately apparent even in the documentation that the registry is just a light wrapper for ArrayObject.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Zend_Registry is a wrapper around **`static`**  type variable storing an array .

Static variable defination from wikipedia

> In computer programming, a static variable is a variable that has been
>   allocated statically — whose lifetime extends across the entire run of
>   the program.

Similarly variables stored inside Zend_Registry extends across the entire run of the program.

A simple My Registry class

```
    class My_Registry
    {
    static $storage;

   public static function set($key,$value)
    {
    self::$storage[$key] = $value;
    }


 public static function get($key)
    {
    return self::$storage[$key];
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`Zend_Registry` is pretty much just an array (it inherits from `ArrayObject`). It doesn't provide persistent storage so there's no need to use session or file.